# symfony2 getlocale in extension or repository

Tags: php, symfony, locale

I want to know current locale in my Twig Extension or Entity Repository. How could I do this?

In default controller I can get it by: `$request->getLocale();`

But I need it in my Extension or Repository, to make query depending from current locale.

Answer (score 0):

Is not the best solution but i think you can do sometig lige this:

-in controler
`$locale = $request->getLocale();`

```
$result = $yourRepo->yourMethodInRepo($locale)
```

in your repo:

```
public function yourMethodInRepos($locale) {}
```

Comment: thank you for your replay, but the problem is that im loading repository from extension, not controller, so i cant access $request.